# How to post JSON data using volley library?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have following format of posting data to server. I want to post these data to server using volley library and following request contains multiple images' base64 content also. I am passing this as StringRequest i got the error of invalid JSON data format. How can i post following data to server? Or any other useful way to pass following data to server then also let me know. So that i can solve this problem and efficiently can upload on server.

```
{
    "TakeoffID": "2",           
    "ViewPhoto1": "image base64 content",
    "ViewPhoto2": "image base64 content",
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "OrderLineid": "964",
            "OrderLinePhoto1": "image base64 content",
            "OrderLinePhoto2": "image base64 content"
        },
        {
            "OrderLineid": "963",
            "OrderLinePhoto1": "image base64 content",
            "OrderLinePhoto2": "image base64 content"
        }
    ]
}
```

===========
Following is my code to upload above data:

```
private void uploadImage(final CustomerBean bean,final String line_items)
{
    // Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, Const.API_SYNC_ALL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s)
        {

            loading.dismiss();              
            Log.print("======UPLOAD IMAGE=====", s);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError)
        {
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
        {


            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            params.put("TakeoffID", "2");
            params.put("ViewPhoto1", bean.photo1);
            params.put("ViewPhoto2", bean.photo2);
            params.put("LineItems", line_items);
            // returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mActivity);

    // Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

===========================

```
And I am getting following error from server.

[
    {
        "code": "-1",
        "message": "The json data format is incorrect"
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you please post the code in use alongside the error message you get?

Comment: @Arthur Gevorkyan, I edited the code and will you explain how can i post my above format data using volley or another efficient way?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer. The good news is that now your question looks comprehensive and will get answered soon. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you can refer to my following sample code:

```
        try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = "http://...";
            // Prepares POST data...
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("TakeoffID", "2");
            jsonBody.put("ViewPhoto1", "image base64 content");
            jsonBody.put("ViewPhoto2", "image base64 content");
            // "OrderLineid": "964"...
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("OrderLineid","964");
            jsonObject1.put("OrderLinePhoto1","image base64 content");
            jsonObject1.put("OrderLinePhoto2","image base64 content");
            // "OrderLineid": "963"...
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject2.put("OrderLineid","963");
            jsonObject2.put("OrderLinePhoto1","image base64 content");
            jsonObject2.put("OrderLinePhoto2","image base64 content");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);
            // "LineItems"...
            jsonBody.put("LineItems", jsonArray);
            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();
            // Volley request...
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                                mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your code is working for me if i'm passing data without image content, But when i pass base 64 content then getting error like "base 64 code is incorrect.Miscalculated data length of content."

Comment: So I think you only need to check your code that encodes base64

Comment: Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_uri);
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
   byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

   encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
I 'm using this code to get base 64 content? Using this i'm getting wrong image content while checking content online. Please help me how to convert image into base64 in right manner

Comment: I have not ever tried with Image Uri like you, I get byte array from InputStream, you can refer my sample code at http://pastebin.com/YDmGVevY

Answer (score 2):

You can also use following block of code for pass json object to Volley as a parameter. Just check it once.

```
JSONObject data= new JSONObject();

            data.accumulate("username", "mobileGps");
            data.accumulate("password", "9565551236");

            JSONObject total= new JSONObject();
            total.put("data",data);

            json = jsonObjectNew.toString();
```